# Объединение регулярок java

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения

Пробую соединить эти два регулярных выражения

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile ("^(([01]?\\d\\d?|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-5])\\.){3}([01]?\\d\\d?|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-5])$"); 
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile ("[a-z0-9-]+\\.(ru|com|net|de|cn|uk|org|info|nl|tk)");
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

С помощью логического ИЛИ это сделать не получается

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile ("[a-z0-9-]+\\.(ru|com|net|de|cn|uk|org|info|nl|tk)"  |
                        "^(([01]?\\d\\d?|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-5])\\.){3}([01]?\\d\\d?|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-5])$");
```

Ошибка

```
java: bad operand types for binary operator '|'
  first type:  java.lang.String
  second type: java.lang.String
```

Comment: Ну, вы пытались логическим ИЛИ воздействовать на строки. Ожидаемая ошибка. А вертикальную черту нужно прямо в строки вставлять, разделяя регулярки. У вас это в первой регулярке уже используется, где вы домены перечисляете

Answer (score 1):

Вот так выглядит паттерн

```
((([01]?\\d\\d?|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-5])\\.){3}([01]?\\d\\d?|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-5]))|([a-z0-9]+\\.(ru|com|net|de|cn|uk|org|info|nl|tk))
```

в Коде так

```
String regex ="((([01]?\\d\\d?|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-5])\\.){3}([01]?\\d\\d?|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-5]))|([a-z0-9]+\\.(ru|com|net|de|cn|uk|org|info|nl|tk))";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
```